# fancybox 2 gallery with nextClick - clicking final image closes it

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

i'm trying out fancybox 2, and i've removed the `arrows`, `closebutton`, and `loop`, and enabled `nextclick`. i'm going for super clean and easy to use.

the problem i'm having now is that I click through the gallery, but when I click the last slide i expect it to close, and it doesn't - clicking the image doesn't do anything.

my guess is the answer is either adding a self-close action via class, like this:

```
<a class="gallery1 closeaction" href=...
```

but i really have no idea. i'd think this kind of thing would be in a demo, but i can't find anything like it.

help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code using the `beforeShow` callback should do the trick :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        arrows: false,
        closeBtn: false,
        loop: false,
        nextClick: true,
        beforeShow: function() {
            var groupLength = this.group.length;
            var thisIndex = this.index + 2; // index starts at "0"
            $(".fancybox-image").on("click", function() {
                if (thisIndex > groupLength) {
                    $.fancybox.close();
                } else {
                    thisIndex++;
                }
            });
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z85dK/)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Something like bind click with last item in gallery

```
$('.fancylink').fancybox({
loop: false,
afterShow: function(){          
    if(this.index  == this.group.length - 1){

        $('.fancyselector').click(function(){
$.fancybox.close(); }); // or :
nextClick :false;
closeClick :true;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. that made the last item in the gallery close immediately, not onclick.

Comment: did you try only nextClick :false;
closeClick :true;

Comment: Ah, the right callback is ofcourse not afterShow but afterLoad

Comment: still not working for me... maybe there's something wrong with if logic?

Answer (score 0):

If You use fancybox ver. 3, You can use this piece of code

```
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        clickContent: function(current, event) {
            var sliderCount = $('.fancybox-infobar span[data-fancybox-count]').text();
            var sliderPosition = current.pos + 1;
            if(sliderPosition < sliderCount){
                return current.type === "image" ? "nextOrClose" : false;
            } else{
                return current.type === "image" ? "close" : false;
            }

        },
    });
```